# Infinite loop C++ Logic errors

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, do-while, logic-error

I have a simple c++ program that has a menu and allows the user to select an option with a number. There is also a block of code that ensures the input from the user is valid, however, when I for example input a letter ("s"). Instead of showing an error message and then allowing the user to input a valid response, I receive an infinite loop of the same error message.
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){

const string PROMPT = ">> ";
int options[3] = {1, 2, 3};
int option;

// Display menu
cout << "MENU" << endl
<< "1\tAdult Tickets" << endl
<<"2\tStudent Tickets" << endl
<< "3\t2 Adults, 2 Children Tickets" << endl << endl;

// Getting option from the user and validating it
do {
// Prompt for input and get option from user
cin >> option;

// Displaying appropriate error messages
if (!isdigit(option)){
  // Invalid data type
  cout << "This is not a valid number!" << endl;
  // Not on the options menu
} else if (!(find(options, options + sizeof(options)/ sizeof(options[0]), option))){
  cout << "This option is not on the menu!" << endl;
}

} while (!isdigit(option) || !(find(options, options + sizeof(options)/ sizeof(options[0]), option)));
return 0;
}
```

This is an example of the output when I input "s"

> This is not a valid number
> This is not a valid number!
> This is not a valid number!
> This is not a valid number!
> This is not a valid number!
> This is not a valid number!
> This is not a valid number!...

Any help will be highly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size)`(options)`instead of `sizeof(options)/ sizeof(options[0])`.  Or use `std::begin(options), std::end(options)` rather than start, start+length

Answer (score 0):

For starters the variable `option` shall have the type `char`.

```
char option;
```

In this case you may apply the function `isdigit` to the entered character.

Also you are incorrectly using the find algorithm in the if statement.

The loop can look the following way.

```
#include <iterator>

//...

char option;
bool valid_input;

do {
    valid_input = false;

    // Prompt for input and get option from user
    cin >> option;

    // Displaying appropriate error messages
    if ( not isdigit( ( unsigned char )option)){
        // Invalid data type
        cout << "This is not a valid number!" << endl;
        // Not on the options menu
    } else if ( find( std::begin( options ), std::end( options ), option - '0') == std::end( options ){
      cout << "This option is not on the menu!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        valid_input = true;
    }
} while ( not valid_input );
```

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why using a `char` for `option` solves the problem. What if the menu had more than 10 options?

Comment: `bool .= valid_input;` ?

Comment: Since I do not use C++11, I get an error when I try to use the find function your way so unfortunately I had to use the method I have shown above. Anyway, thank you so much for feedback, I will definitely be using your advice.

Comment: @TerrySikenaris In any case you have to compare the result of the algorithm find with the end iterator.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to resolve this is to create a variable tracking validity. Like an int where 0 means it is valid while 1 or more can be invalid, then just have your loop condition check the variable.